# Implementation of forward chaining in prolog (SWI-Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I would like to implement forward-chaining reasoning in Prolog. I made up a simple KB of facts and some rules, from which I should be able to get the fact `green(fritz)`.
I tried to implement it but somehow, when `member` fails, it stops going on.

```
/*
meta rules
*/

rule(1, [canary(X)], [sings(X), chips(X)]).
rule(2, [frog(X)], [croaks(X), eats_flies(X)]).
rule(3, [green(X)], [frog(X)]).
rule(4, [yellow(X)], [canary(X)]).

/*
meta facts
*/

fact(1, eats_flies(fritz)).
fact(2, croaks(fritz)).
fact(3, sings(tweety)).
fact(4, chips(tweety)).
fact(5, croaks(kroger)).
fact(6, chips(kroger)).

/*
forward chaining
*/

start_id(100000).

get_id(Y) :-
    retract(start_id(X)),
    Y is X + 1,
    assert(start_id(Y)).

forward(NewFacts) :-
    findall(rule(Id, Head, Tail), rule(Id, Head, Tail), Rules),
    findall(fact(Id, X), fact(Id, X), Facts),
    forward_chaining(Rules, Facts, NewFacts).

forward_chaining(_, [], _).
forward_chaining([], _, _).
forward_chaining([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], [fact(Id, X)|Facts], NewFactsRec + NewFactsRecRec) :-
    forward_rule([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], fact(Id, X), NewFactsRec, NewRulesRec),
    forward_chaining(NewRulesRec + Rules, NewFactsRec + Facts, NewFactsRecRec).

forward_rule([], _, _, _).
forward_rule([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], fact(Id, X), NewFacts, NewRules) :-
    member(X, Tail) ->
        (    
            delete(Tail, X, NewTail),    
            NewTail = [] ->
                get_id(NewId),
                NovelFact = [fact(NewId, Head)],
                NovelRule = []
                ;
                NovelFact = [],
                NovelRule = [rule(Id, Head, NewTail)]
            
        );
        NovelRule = [rule(Id, Head, Tail)],
    forward_rule(Rules, fact(Id, X), NewFactsRec, NewRulesRec),
    append(NewRulesRec, NovelRule, NewRules),
    append(NewFactsRec, NovelFact, NewFacts).
```

Focusing on the `forward_rule` implementation, I would like to check if the `fact` is in the `tail` of a rule. If it is, then it should be removed. If not, I should go on removing the `fact` from all the rules. And then, via the `forward_chaining` implementation, that should be done for every `fact`.
Of course, if the `tail` is empty, the `head` should become a new `fact`. If the `tail` is not empty, the `rule` must be updated.

Am I missing something??

### EDIT 1:

After Isabelle Newbie's answer I tryied to fix the code. Now the if-then-else are working properly.
But still, the recursive call to `forward_rule` fails before starting.

```
start_id(100000).

get_id(Y) :-
    retract(start_id(X)),
    Y is X + 1,
    assert(start_id(Y)).

forward(NewFacts) :-
    findall(rule(Id, Head, Tail), rule(Id, Head, Tail), Rules),
    findall(fact(Id, X), fact(Id, X), Facts),
    forward_chaining(Rules, Facts, NewFacts).

forward_chaining(_, [], _).
forward_chaining([], _, _).
forward_chaining([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], [fact(Id, X)|Facts], NewFacts) :-
    forward_rule([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], fact(Id, X), NewFactsRec, NewRulesRec),
    writeln('going on'),    % debug
    append(Rules, NewRulesRec, ToForwardRules),
    append(Facts, NewFactsRec, ToForwardFacts),
    forward_chaining(ToForwardRules, ToForwardFacts, NewFacts).



forward_rule([], _Fact, [], []).
forward_rule([rule(Id, Head, Tail)|Rules], fact(Id, X), NewFacts, NewRules) :-
    (   member(X, Tail) 
    ->  delete(Tail, X, NewTail),
        writeln('is member'),    % debug
            (   NewTail = [] 
            ->  get_id(NewId),
                writeln('newtail is empty'),    % debug
                NovelFact = [fact(NewId, Head)],
                NovelRule = []
            ;
                writeln('newtail is not empty'),    % debug
                NovelFact = [],
                NovelRule = [rule(Id, Head, NewTail)])
            
    ;
        writeln('is not member'),   % debug
        NovelRule = [rule(Id, Head, Tail)],
        NovelFact = []),
    writeln('postlude'),    % debug
    forward_rule(Rules, fact(Id, X), NewFactsRec, NewRulesRec),
    append(NewRulesRec, NovelRule, NewRules),
    append(NewFactsRec, NovelFact, NewFacts).
```

I'm using `gtrace` to try to understand where the code fails. So I saw that it is not entering the recursive call. It seems that there is an unification problem, but I don't understand why.
[image: gtrace status]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work correctly, the forward chaining algorithm cannot *remove*, nor *modify*, the rules that are fired in each iteration (otherwise the implementation will not work for recursive rules). The algorithm terminates when a **fixpoint** is obtained (or, alternatively, when a *ground fact* to be proved is derived).

For a more uniform representation, facts can be represented as rules
with condition `true`. Also, to distinguish different knowledge bases,
rules can be labeled with a knowledge base identifier.

```
:- op(1100, xfx, if).
:- op(1000, xfy, and). % <== EDITED

forward(KB, Fact) :-
    fixpoint(KB, nil, [true], Facts),
    member(Fact, Facts).

fixpoint(_, Base, Base, Base) :- !.
fixpoint(KB, _, Base, Facts) :-
    setof(Fact, derived(Fact, KB, Base), NewFacts),
    ord_union(NewFacts, Base, NewBase),
    fixpoint(KB, Base, NewBase, Facts).

derived(Fact, KB, Base) :-
    rule(KB : Fact if Condition),
    satisfy(Base, Condition).

satisfy(Base, Condition) :-
    (   Condition = (A and B)
    ->  member(A, Base),
        satisfy(Base, B)
    ;   member(Condition, Base) ).


% first knowledge base

rule(1 : eats_flies(fritz) if true).
rule(1 : croaks(fritz)     if true).
rule(1 : sings(tweety)     if true).
rule(1 : chips(tweety)     if true).
rule(1 : has_wings(tweety) if true). % <== EDITED
rule(1 : croaks(kroger)    if true).
rule(1 : chips(kroger)     if true).
rule(1 : frog(X)           if croaks(X) and eats_flies(X)).
rule(1 : green(X)          if frog(X)).
rule(1 : yellow(X)         if canary(X)).
rule(1 : canary(X)         if sings(X) and chips(X) and has_wings(X)). % <== EDITED

% second knowledge base (recursive example)

rule(2 : connected(a,b) if true).
rule(2 : connected(b,c) if true).
rule(2 : connected(c,d) if true).
rule(2 : connected(X,Z) if connected(X,Y) and connected(Y,Z)).
```

Examples:

```
?- forward(1, canary(X)).
X = tweety ;
false.

?- forward(1, green(X)).
X = fritz ;
false.

?- forward(2, connected(a,X)).
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
false.
```

**Remark** A least fixpoint exists whenever the knowledge base is *function-free* (i.e., it has a finite Herbrand model).

Comment: What if I want the conditions to be more than two? I would like to have them of variable length, how should I handle this case? I would like to understand better that definition of the operators and the use of setof, which is not so clear to me.

Comment: let's say that now  `canary(X) if sings(X) and chips(X) and has_wings(X).`

Comment: this works `canary(X) if sings(X) and (chips(X) and has_wings(X))).` , but for longer rules it would have a lot of brackets and become really hard to read

Comment: another thing not clear to me is that `_` in `fixpoint(KB, _, Base, Facts)`. If it is not used, what does it represent? Is it necessary?

Comment: @juuso There was a typo in the definition of the and operator, which I've already fixed. Now a rule can have any number of conditions, without the need to use additional parentheses.

Comment: yes now that's working

Comment: @juuso `_` is an anonymous variable (whose value is irrelevant), as the value of this argument has already been used in the first clause of the predicate `fixpoint/4` to check whether the fixed point has been reached.

Comment: @juuso The predicate `setof/3` is similar to the predicate `findall/3`, but it eliminates repeated elements and sorts the resulting list.

Comment: ok, now it makes sense, thanks. May I ask you something in chat? I'm voting this as best answer but I would like to keep talking about this if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241394/discussion-between-slago-and-juuso).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here.

Problem 1 is that the non-recursive clauses for your recursive predicates look like this:

```
forward_rule([], _, _, _).
```

This means: "If the list of rules is empty, arbitrary facts correspond to arbitrary new facts and arbitrary new rules."

For example:

```
?- forward_rule([], apple_pie, [new_fact_1, new_fact_2, new_fact3], [new_rule_1, new_rule_2]).
true.
```

You almost certainly meant something more like:

```
forward_rule([], _Fact, [], []).
```

meaning: "If the list of rules is empty, no matter what `_Fact` might be, there are no new facts and no new rules to derive."

Problem 2 is in lines like this:

```
forward_chaining(NewRulesRec + Rules, NewFactsRec + Facts, NewFactsRecRec).
```

This looks a bit like you're trying to use `+` as a list append function. There are no functions in Prolog. You know how to use `append`, but you will have to use it for this as well.

Problem 3 is around your if-then-else code. Your formatting doesn't reflect what will actually happen.

Consider:

```
conditional(C) :-
    writeln(unconditional_prelude),
    C = true ->
        (
            writeln(true_branch_1),
            writeln(true_branch_2)
        );
        writeln(presumably_false_branch),
    writeln(presumably_unconditional_postlude).
```

This gives:

```
?- conditional(true).
unconditional_prelude
true_branch_1
true_branch_2
true.

?- conditional(false).
unconditional_prelude
presumably_false_branch
presumably_unconditional_postlude
true.
```

See how non-indented part "after" the conditional is in fact part of the false branch?

Often a separate predicate definition can be clearer than the if-then-else construct. For example, you could write something like:

```
x_tail_novelfact_novelrule(X, Tail, NovelFact, NovelRule) :-
    member(X, Tail),
    ... rest of "true" branch ...
x_tail_novelfact_novelrule(X, Tail, NovelFact, NovelRule) :-
    \+ member(X, Tail),
    ... rest of "false" branch ...
```

If you must use the if-then-else construct, you must put parentheses **around the whole if-then-else**. Like this:

```
... prelude ...
(    Condition1,
     Condition2
->   TrueBranch1,
     TrueBranch2
;    FalseBranch1,
     FalseBranch2 ),
... postlude ...
```

Only (at most) one of the branches will be executed. No matter which branch is executed, if it succeeds, then the postlude will be executed.

There might be other problems with your code as well, but I hope this helps get you started with fixing things for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very clear.

Comment: I edited the question with the code fixed (I hope). Now I have a problem with the recursive call to forward_rule