# Forward chaining in Prolog, problem with multiple rules

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70821997/implementation-of-forward-chaining-in-prolog-swi-prolog)'s best answer, I found a good example of forward chaining in Prolog. I have modified it a bit, but there is a problem with the last rule I tried to define (`path`). It doesn't work. With the current facts, I should be able to derive the `path([a,b,c,d,e])`, but it doesn't work.

Forward code:

```
:- op(1100, xfx, if).
:- op(1000, xfy, and).
:- op(900, xfy, or).
:- dynamic rule/1.                                                       

forward(Facts) :-
    fixed_point(nil, [true], Facts).                % Start with the base with only true

fixed_point(Base, Base, Base) :- !.                 % Reached a fixpoint
fixed_point(_, Base, Facts) :-                      % Base =/= Facts => not a fixpoint
    setof(Fact, derived(Fact, Base), NewFacts),     % Derive new facts
    ord_union(NewFacts, Base, NewBase),             % Add new facts to base
    fixed_point(Base, NewBase, Facts).              % Repeat with new base

derived(Fact, Base) :-                              
    rule(Fact if Condition),                        % Match a rule
    satisfy(Base, Condition).                       % Verify if condition is satisfied given base

satisfy(Base, Condition) :-
    Condition =.. [and, Elem|Bag],!,
    member(Elem, Base),                                     
    (   Bag = []
    ->  true
    ;   NewAtom =.. [and|Bag],       
        satisfy(Base, NewAtom)).
satisfy(Base, Condition) :-
    Condition =.. [or, Elem|Bag],!,
    (   member(Elem, Base)
    ->  true
    ;   (   Bag = []
        ->  false
        ;   NewAtom =.. [or|Bag],       
            satisfy(Base, NewAtom))).
satisfy(Base, Condition) :-
    member(Condition, Base),!.
satisfy(_, true):-!.
satisfy(_, false):-!,fail.
```

Here are rules and facts:

```
rule(eats_flies(fritz) if true).
rule(croaks(fritz)     if true).
rule(eats_flies(frotz) if true). % ADDED IN EDIT
rule(croaks(frotz)     if true). % ADDED IN EDIT
rule(sings(tweety)     if true).
rule(chips(tweety)     if true).
rule(has_wings(tweety) if true).
rule(croaks(krogr)    if true).
rule(chips(kroger)     if true).
rule(canary(X)         if and(sings(X),chips(X),has_wings(X))).
rule(frog(X)           if and(croaks(X),eats_flies(X))).
rule(green(X)          if frog(X)).
rule(yellow(X)         if canary(X)).
rule(node(a) if true).
rule(node(b) if true).
rule(node(c) if true).
rule(node(d) if true).
rule(node(e) if true).
rule(connected(a,b) if true).
rule(connected(b,c) if true).
rule(connected(c,d) if true).
rule(connected(d,e) if true).
rule(funny(c,d) if true).
rule(wonderful(X,Y) if or(nice(X,Y),funny(X,Y))).
rule(connected(X,Z) if and(connected(X,Y),connected(Y,Z))).
rule(path([Node|[]]) if node(Node)).
rule(path([Node, NextNode|Nodes]) if and(connected(Node, NextNode),path([NextNode|Nodes]))).
```

Critical rules:

```
rule(path([Node|[]]) if node(Node)).
rule(path([Node, NextNode|Nodes]) if and(connected(Node, NextNode),path([NextNode|Nodes]))).
```

What I get as output of the forward:

```
?- forward(A).
A = [true,canary(tweety),chips(kroger),chips(tweety),croaks(fritz),croaks(krogr),eats_flies(fritz),frog(fritz),green(fritz),has_wings(tweety),node(a),node(b),node(c),node(d),node(e),path([a]),sings(tweety),yellow(tweety),connected(a,b),connected(a,c),connected(b,c),connected(c,d),connected(d,e),funny(c,d),wonderful(c,d)].
```

## EDIT:

Testing the code I found out that another problem is that if I add similar rules, such as:

```
rule(eats_flies(fritz) if true).
rule(croaks(fritz)     if true).
rule(eats_flies(frotz) if true).
rule(croaks(frotz)     if true).
```

The forward will only find that `fritz` is a `frog`, but not `frotz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems in your code are:

- Inappropriate use of operator *univ* (`=..`), just use unification (`=`). See why:

  ```
  ?- (p and q and r) =.. [and,G|Gs], N =.. [and|Gs].
  G = p,                        % <== this is the first goal of the condition
  Gs = [(q and r)],
  N = and((q and r)).           % <== this IS NOT a valid conjunction of the remaining goals

  ?- (p and q and r) = (G and Gs).
  G = p,                        % <== this is the first goal of the condition
  Gs =  (q and r).              % <== this IS a valid conjunction of the remaining goals
  ```
- Do not use cut in `satisfy(Base, Condition) :- member(Condition, Base), !.`, as this prevents predicate `member/2` backtracking to find alternative answers (e.g., `frog(fritz)` and `frog(frotz)`).
- As initially `Base` is the set `[true]`, there is no need for the clause `satisfy(_, true) :- !.`. Note that `true` is already naturally satisfied by clause `satisfy(Base, Condition) :- member(Condition, Base)`.
- In Prolog, you only need to declare what is true, so there is no need for the clause `satisfy(_, false):- !, fail.`.

Taking into account all these observations, a correct code is as follows:

```
:- op(1100, xfx, if).
:- op(1000, xfy, and).
:- op(900, xfy, or).
:- dynamic rule/1.

forward(Facts) :-
    fixed_point(nil, [true], Facts).                % Start with the base with only true

fixed_point(Base, Base, Base) :- !.                 % Reached a fixpoint
fixed_point(_, Base, Facts) :-                      % Base =/= Facts => not a fixpoint
    setof(Fact, derived(Fact, Base), NewFacts),     % Derive new facts
    ord_union(NewFacts, Base, NewBase),             % Add new facts to base
    fixed_point(Base, NewBase, Facts).              % Repeat with new base

derived(Fact, Base) :-
    rule(Fact if Condition),                        % Match a rule
    satisfy(Base, Condition).                       % Verify if condition is satisfied given base

satisfy(Base, G and Gs) :-    % Condition unifies with (G and Gs)
    !,
    member(G, Base),
    satisfy(Base, Gs).

satisfy(Base, G or Gs) :-     % Condition unifies with (G or Gs)
    !,
    (   member(G, Base)
    ;   satisfy(Base, Gs) ).

satisfy(Base, Condition) :-   % Condition is an atomic proposition
    member(Condition, Base).

% Knowledge base

rule(eats_flies(fritz) if true).
rule(croaks(fritz)     if true).
rule(eats_flies(frotz) if true). 
rule(croaks(frotz)     if true). 
rule(sings(tweety)     if true).
rule(chips(tweety)     if true).
rule(has_wings(tweety) if true).
rule(croaks(krogr)    if true).
rule(chips(kroger)     if true).
rule(canary(X)         if and(sings(X),chips(X),has_wings(X))).
rule(frog(X)           if and(croaks(X),eats_flies(X))).
rule(green(X)          if frog(X)).
rule(yellow(X)         if canary(X)).
rule(node(a) if true).
rule(node(b) if true).
rule(node(c) if true).
rule(node(d) if true).
rule(node(e) if true).
rule(connected(a,b) if true).
rule(connected(b,c) if true).
rule(connected(c,d) if true).
rule(connected(d,e) if true).
rule(funny(c,d) if true).
rule(wonderful(X,Y) if or(nice(X,Y),funny(X,Y))).
rule(connected(X,Z) if and(connected(X,Y),connected(Y,Z))).
rule(path([Node|[]]) if node(Node)).
rule(path([Node, NextNode|Nodes]) if and(connected(Node, NextNode),path([NextNode|Nodes]))).
```

Examples:

```
?- forward(Base), member(path(P), Base), length(P, 5).
Base = [true, chips(kroger), chips(tweety), croaks(fritz), croaks(frotz), croaks(krogr), eats_flies(fritz), eats_flies(frotz), frog(...)|...],
P = [a, b, c, d, e] .

?- forward(Base), member(frog(X), Base).
Base = [true, chips(kroger), chips(tweety), croaks(fritz), croaks(frotz), croaks(krogr), eats_flies(fritz), eats_flies(frotz), frog(...)|...],
X = fritz ;
Base = [true, chips(kroger), chips(tweety), croaks(fritz), croaks(frotz), croaks(krogr), eats_flies(fritz), eats_flies(frotz), frog(...)|...],
X = frotz ;
false.
```

**REMARK** I didn't check the correctness of all your code, just the most relevant parts to get the answers you wanted. But I saw that the precedence you assigned to the operator **or** is not adequate, as the logical connective **or** has lower priority than the logical connective **and** (note that, in predicate [`op/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3), smaller numbers indicate higher priorities).

Comment: Clear as always, thank you senpai