# Forward chaining in prolog with rules about lists

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

In [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999525/forward-chaining-in-prolog-problem-with-multiple-rules), we built a simple forward chaining in Prolog together with the user [slago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11535940/slago), and solved some problems about it.
Code for forward chaining:

```
:- op(1100, xfx, if).
:- op(1000, xfy, or).
:- op(900, xfy, and).                        

forward(Facts) :-
    fixed_point(nil, [true], Facts).                % Start with the base with only true

fixed_point(Base, Base, Base) :- !.                 % Reached a fixpoint
fixed_point(_, Base, Facts) :-                      % Base =/= Facts => not a fixpoint
    setof(Fact, derived(Fact, Base), NewFacts),     % Derive new facts
    ord_union(NewFacts, Base, NewBase),             % Add new facts to base
    fixed_point(Base, NewBase, Facts).              % Repeat with new base

derived(Fact, Base) :-                              
    rule(Fact if Condition),                        % Match a rule
    satisfy(Base, Condition).                       % Verify if condition is satisfied given base

satisfy(Base, G and Gs) :-                          % Condition is a conjunction
    !,
    member(G, Base),
    satisfy(Base, Gs).
satisfy(Base, G or Gs) :-                           % Condition is a disjunction
    !,
    (   member(G, Base)
    ;   satisfy(Base, Gs) ).
satisfy(_, callp(X)) :-                             % Condition is a callable fact
    !,
    call(X).
satisfy(Base, Condition) :-                         % Condition is an atomic proposition
    member(Condition, Base).
```

Simple knowledge base to test it:

```
rule(eats_flies(fritz) if true).
rule(croaks(fritz)     if true).
rule(eats_flies(frotz) if true).
rule(croaks(frotz)     if true).
rule(sings(tweety)     if true).
rule(chips(tweety)     if true).
rule(has_wings(tweety) if true).
rule(croaks(krogr)    if true).
rule(chips(kroger)     if true).
rule(canary(X)         if and(sings(X),chips(X),has_wings(X))).
rule(frog(X)           if and(croaks(X),eats_flies(X))).
rule(green(X)          if frog(X)).
rule(yellow(X)         if canary(X)).
rule(node(a) if true).
rule(node(b) if true).
rule(node(c) if true).
rule(node(d) if true).
rule(node(e) if true).
rule(connected(a,b) if true).
rule(connected(b,c) if true).
rule(connected(c,d) if true).
rule(connected(d,e) if true).
rule(funny(c,d) if true).
rule(wonderful(X,Y) if or(nice(X,Y),funny(X,Y))).
rule(connected(X,Z) if and(connected(X,Y),connected(Y,Z))).
rule(path([Node|[]]) if node(Node)).
rule(path([Node, NextNode|Nodes]) if and(connected(Node, NextNode),path([NextNode|Nodes]))).
rule(int(1) if true).
rule(int(0) if true).
rule(int(2) if true).
rule(iszero(X) if and(int(X), callp(X = 0))).

rule(has_at_least_n([_|Tail], 0) if true).
rule(has_at_least_n([X|Tail], N) if and(node(X), callp(NewN is N-1), has_at_least_n(Tail, NewN))).
rule(has_at_least_n([X|Tail], N) if and(has_at_least_n(Tail, N))).
```

Now I would like to solve a problem with the last rules about lists. I would like to be able to count the elements of a list. So I would like to be able to say, for example, that the list:

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

has at least 5 nodes,
and a list like:

```
[a,x,y,c,d]
```

has not 5 nodes

with the rule I built, the forward loops itself by finding every time a fact like:

```
has_at_least_n([_|_], 0)
```

since every time it can unify that `_` with anything.

Any tips on how should I handle this case? How can I have rules on lists avoiding infinite loops?

Still my forward is not able to find any other rule different from the dummy one with the `has_at_least_n([_|_], 0)`.

### **EDIT**:

Using `gtrace` for debugging, I found out that, if the `and` or the `or` have more than two facts inside the brackets, it is not recognized as `satisfy(Base, G and Gs)` /  `satisfy(Base, G or Gs)`, but only `satisfy(Base, Condition)`, and of course the `member(Condition, Base)` is false since `and(..., ..., ..., ...)` is not in `Base`.

When there are just two facts, instead, I see in the debugger that they have a different representation : `fact1 and fact2`
And this matches the rule.

Comment: Note that if there is at least one node, there will be infinitely many lists with at least *n* elements. For example, from the facts `node(a)` and `has_at_least_n([], 0)`, you can derive `has_at_least_n([a], 0)`, `has_at_least_n([a,a], 0)`, `has_at_least_n([a,a, a], 0)`, ... Therefore, there is no way to compute a fixed point. An alternative could be to define another version of the predicate `forward`, which takes as input the base and a maximum number of iterations, and which can stop in two situations (1) if a fixed point is reached or (2) if the maximum number of iterations is reached.

Comment: Recall that there is a least fixed point if, and only if, the knowledge base is function-free (that is, it has a finite Herbrand model). Since a list is symbolically represented by a function composition, for example `list(a,list(b,list(c,nil)))`, a program that processes lists is not function-free.

Comment: ok, so I think that the best option is to use that maximum number of iterations. But anyway, my forward is not finding facts such as `has_at_least_n([a, a, a], 0)`, only the ones with `has_at_least_n(_, 0)`

Comment: it turned out that, if i have more than two facts in an `and` or an  `or`, they are not recognized, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested before, a possible solution is as follows:

```
:- op(1100, xfx, if).
:- op(1000, xfy, or).
:- op(900, xfy, and).

forward(Steps, FinalBase) :-
    forward_iteration(Steps, nil, [true], FinalBase).                 % Current base is [true]

forward_iteration(Steps, PreviousBase, CurrentBase, FinalBase) :-
    (   ( Steps = 0                                                   % Reached max iterations
        ; PreviousBase = CurrentBase )                                % Reached a fixed point
    ->  FinalBase = CurrentBase
    ;   setof(Fact, derived(Fact, CurrentBase), NewFacts),            % Derive new facts
        ord_union(NewFacts, CurrentBase, NewBase),                    % Add new facts into current base
        succ(Steps0, Steps),
        forward_iteration(Steps0, CurrentBase, NewBase, FinalBase) ). % Repeat with new base

derived(Fact, Base) :-
    rule(Fact if Condition),                                          % Match a rule
    satisfy(Base, Condition).                                         % Condition holds in current base

satisfy(Base, G and Gs) :-                                            % Condition is a conjunction
    !,
    member(G, Base),
    satisfy(Base, Gs).

satisfy(Base, G or Gs) :-                                            % Condition is a disjunction
    !,
    (   member(G, Base)
    ;   satisfy(Base, Gs) ).

satisfy(_Base, call(Fact)) :-                                        % Condition is a callable fact
    !,
    call(Fact).

satisfy(Base, Condition) :-                                          % Condition is an atomic proposition
    member(Condition, Base).
```

Note that `and` is a binary operator, not an arbitrary arity functor! So, for example, we can define `len/2` as:

```
rule(item(X) if call(member(X, [a,b,c]))).
rule(len([], 0) if true).
rule(len([H|T], N) if len(T,M) and item(H) and call(succ(M,N))).
```

Running examples:

```
?- forward(1, FinalBase), maplist(writeln, FinalBase).
true
item(a)
item(b)
item(c)
len([],0)
FinalBase = [true, item(a), item(b), item(c), len([], 0)].

?- forward(2, FinalBase), maplist(writeln, FinalBase).
true
item(a)
item(b)
item(c)
len([],0)
len([a],1)
len([b],1)
len([c],1)
FinalBase = [true, item(a), item(b), item(c), len([], 0), len([a], 1), len([b], 1), len([...], 1)].

?- forward(3, FinalBase), maplist(writeln, FinalBase).
true
item(a)
item(b)
item(c)
len([],0)
len([a],1)
len([a,a],2)
len([a,b],2)
len([a,c],2)
len([b],1)
len([b,a],2)
len([b,b],2)
len([b,c],2)
len([c],1)
len([c,a],2)
len([c,b],2)
len([c,c],2)
FinalBase = [true, item(a), item(b), item(c), len([], 0), len([a], 1), len([a|...], 2), len([...|...], 2), len(..., ...)|...].
```